# Removing debris from PCB

Tags: pcb-fabrication, short-circuit, debugging

I have a PCB with no solder mask with a very dense layout and a very fine trace spacing.

I didn't get a solder mask because it's still in the prototyping phase, and it's way cheaper.

I keep having to stop, find the new shorts that keep popping up, and remove metal fibers that are barely visible.

From what I can tell the fibers are aluminum from the pcb so a magnet is no help.

Is there a trick to remove them faster or a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Aluminum?  That would be rare as aluminum is pretty much only used for the heat sink layer of a metal core pcb.  More likely you're learning about [Tin whiskers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whisker_(metallurgy)) and would benefit from reading more about them.  I don't know the answer to this question the way you've phrased it other than "better tools, use solder mask"

Comment: compressed air?

Comment: Compressed air didn't help. Your right it is Tin... I looked at "whiskering" on wikipedia, that seems to be whats happening. Tomorrow I'll get some solder on the problem traces and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Who did the soldering?

Comment: Yes, there is one proven way: USE MORE FLUX.

Comment: I did the soldering,used tons of flux... The problems are not at the solder pads but on the long traces that have 7-8mil spacing.

Comment: Are you saying that the boards were delivered with plating having a lot of hairwires? What size are your PCBs?

Comment: HUGE. And I put strain on the boards when taking them in/out of the edge card connectors.

Comment: 8 mil spacing is not really "very fine". Most shops will happily do 4 mil. It would be interesting to check if they actually gave you the tin-lead solder you requested --- maybe they gave you lead-free if that would reduce their costs (Most of the very-low-cost services will not even read your fab notes, just run them according to their "standard" process).

Comment: I did the soldering... I believe I fix the problem areas by getting some lead solder on the traces. So far no more issues.

Comment: For large copper planes is it better to do hatching vs solid copper to reduce board stress when its being heated?

Answer (score 6):

The trick to stop this from happening is to order your PCB with solder mask. Do consider the cost of your time when deciding that it is cheaper to order boards without.

Comment: I got this board w/ 1 day turn around time with overnight shipping for $250 vs paying over $2000 and 5 day turn around when including a solder mask for a design that hasn't been proven.

Comment: You might also want to consider using leaded solder, as lead inhibits the formation of whiskers, if that is your problem. As long as you dispose of it properly, there's nothing wrong with using lead in your prototypes, just try to keep it out of any final products.

Comment: Yep, that's all we use. All of our designs are just for internal use.

Comment: Did you end up using more or less than $1750 worth of your time finding and fixing shorts, though?

Comment: And if you add a couple of days looking for the shorts (or if they show up as glitches in the future), that 2000$ price tag falls drastically for 48hr and 72hr fabrication.

Comment: Search for circuit board aggregators in your area.  In the US we have OshPark (and probably others, but I like purple).  You'll need to wait longer (OshPark is several days to two weeks, depending on where you hit them in their cycle), but you'll get a regular PCB.

Comment: You can run an x-acto knife backward between all the traces (backward meaning to scrape, rather than to cut).  That seems to clear the whiskers.

Comment: Definitely did not spend $1750 finding shorts, 10hrs max. OshPark looks pretty good, we usually use Advanced Circuits.